# PHP session cookie not extending timeout on activity

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

## Scenario

- User visits at 2:00:00PM and a session is assigned that will expire in 30 minutes.
- User continues activity with requests to the server for 30+ minutes.
- User's session expires at 2:30:00PM (30 minutes later) even though they have been active *with requests to the server* the entire time.

How do I make the session cookie always update the expiration date for *both* the client and the server so the expiration is extended (in this case, 30 minutes) each time the client makes a request to the server?

```
<?php
session_name('session');
session_start();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `setcookie` *after* `session_start()` is working as expected.

```
<?php
session_name('session');
session_start();
setcookie(session_name(), session_id(), time() + 3600, '/');
?>
```